# Stack Overflow videos

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I searched for "`StackOverflow`" on YouTube and it returned about 9,000 results. I discovered [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adAqQct3vRI) and found it beneficial.

Could you include a link to some or your videos in online help?

Comment: Videos aren't good resource for programming mostly.

Comment: Oh, but seeing @Oded explaining how Stack Overflow should be used in live action is nice though :-) ... Reverted my 1st compulsory votings

Comment: [I has been early adopter too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L2yb5.png)

Comment: That video no longer seems to be available.

Comment: Delete the question then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, as there is such (quality) material available I'd fully support to add this to the relevant sections in the online help.

---

Though I have my doubts that videos are really a good medium to teach anything, compared to textual information.

But that might be a generation conflict, people younger than me seem to have gained a different perceiption.

Comment: Good point.  However, that fact that the videos were even made must indicate that the Stack Exchange team believes that they have some value.